# How to Implement Custom Selenium WebElement FindElement

Tags: vb.net, selenium

I want to create a custom `WebElement` from `IWebElement` and then implement `FindElement` to locate an element in my internal list of elements in `m_Elements`:

I have this snippet so far:

```
Imports OpenQA.Selenium
Imports OpenQA.Selenium.By
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class MyWebElement
    Implements IWebElement

    Private m_Elements As New List(Of MyWebElement)

   Public Function FindElement(byObj As By) As IWebElement Implements ISearchContext.FindElement

'
End Function
```

If I look at byObj in Visual Studio I see:
Equals, FindElement, FindElements, GetHasCode, GetType, ToString.

If I look at `byObj` in the debugger I see:
Description, FindElementMethod, and FindElementsMethod

How do I determine what `By` class was used by the caller? `By.Id`, `By.TagName`, etc.

How do I get the `SearchContext`?

Comment: To create a customized find element, simply extend [By.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/By.cs). To create a customized web element with your own methods, you'll have to extend [RemoteWebDriver.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs) and override `CreateElement`.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to test functions which scrape data from a web page. If I run the entire scrape application it takes a long time to start the browser, login to the site, do a search for the desired records, check search results, and the finally scrape the actual data I want from the web page showing the full details of the records.

Comment: I'm trying to test functions which scrape data from a web page. If I run the entire scrape application it takes a long time to start the browser, login to the site, do a search for the desired records, check search results, and finally scrape the actual data I want from the web page showing the full details of the records. Say I have a function which scrapes data from the cells in a table row. I want to test that function. I want to create a TR WebElement, create TD WebElements with test data and then add to the TR element. Then call the ScrapeTR function passing in the TR element.